# Prove $U=\dfrac{a_{pqr}f'(S)}{S_1-S_2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{S_1+\epsilon}{S-S_1}-\dfrac{S_2+\epsilon}{S-S_2}\right)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Given, $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t} = a_{pqr}f(t)-b_{pqr}U+\epsilon(V-U)-MU+S$

Prove $L(U)=\dfrac{a_{pqr}L(f(S))}{S_1-S_2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{S_1+\epsilon}{S-S_1}-\dfrac{S_2+\epsilon}{S-S_2}\right)$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the roots of quadratic equation $S^2+(b_{pqr}+\epsilon+\gamma+M-S)+\epsilon b_{pqr}$

**Following is my attempt:-**

Applying laplace transform on both sides of the given equation

$L\left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t}\right)= a_{pqr}L(f(t))-b_{pqr}L(U)+\epsilon L(V-U)-ML(U)+S\tag{1}$

$SL(U)=a_{pqr}+L(f(S))-b_{pqr}L(U)+\epsilon\left(L(V)-L(U)\right)-ML(U)+S\tag{2}$

In order to obtain U, I tried to take laplace inverse for equation $(2)$

$SL^{-1}(L(U))=a_{pqr}+L^{-1}(L(f(S))-b_{pqr}L^{-1}(L(U))+\epsilon(L^{-1}(L(V))-L^{-1}(L(U)))-ML^{-1}(L(U))+S\tag{3}$

$SU=a_{pqr}+f(S)-b_{pqr}U+\epsilon(V-U)-MU+S\tag{4}$

But I am not getting how to achieve the final proof from here. Please help me in this.

Comment: It feels like the equation is linear in $U$ : are $V,M,S,a_{pqr},b_{pqr}$ constants or do they depend on $t$? Finally, which textbook/paper are you seeing this problem from? Also, $\gamma$ seems to come out of nowhere in the quadratic equation while not being mentioned in the differential equation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, $ V, M, S, a_{pqr}, b_{pqr} $ are not dependent on $t$. Also I have attached the paper which I am trying to go through:- 

https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1016/S0017-9310(02)00503-3

Comment: Thank you for the link. I see the $\gamma$ coming from the equation $(14)$, which shows that $V$ is a function of $t$ as well. You cannot consider $(13)$ and its Laplace transform in isolation, then.